# Adding a dropdown list to the browser through google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to add a dropdown menu to chrome browser through a google chrome extension
so the user can chose an option lets say color and then the extension can apply that color to
the background or something else? Note I am interested in adding a dropdown to the chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change browser's menu. You can:

- add icon with optional popup to the toolbar (browser action),
- add icon to the url bar (page action),
- add item to page's context menu.

That's the only changes you can make to browser's interface. Based on your task I would go with browser action with popup.